# Altering the Last Byte of a String

Tags: python, string, byte, arrays, padding-oracle-attack

I'm working on a Padding Oracle attack and which involves altering an IV and sending it back with a HTML post request. The simple version is that I'm trying to alter the last byte of a string....and I think I might be doing it wrong. First we start out with a Raw IV from the Oracle.

```
IV = 'NFhS0jOCAR0ymB2MM+3Pfg=='
```

We can't work with that so we do base-64 decoding on it.

```
IV = base64.b64decode(IV)
```

That turns it into garbage on our screen (4XR�3�2��3��~) but now it's in a form that we can work with. Now we want to find out the last byte of the IV so we say

```
LastByte = IV[len(IV)-1]
```

Which gives us "~" as the last byte. NOW things get crazy, we want to change the last byte of the IV by XOR'ing it with a number we will call X.

```
NewByte = ord(LastByte) ^ x
newIV = IV[:len(IV)-1] + str(NewByte)
```

And then we base64 encode it and move on

```
newIV = base64.b64encode(newIV)
```

When I check the length of the newIV it's the same length as the original raw IV but I just feel like something isn't right here. Am I messing it up by doing str(NewByte)? I feel like I should be doing this with a bytearray somehow but I don't know enough about using them do it in one. Did I alter the last byte correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [`chr()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) to turn your XORed integer back into a one-character string:

```
NewByte = chr(ord(LastByte) ^ x)
```

`chr()` is the inverse of `ord()`:

```
>>> ord('~')
126
>>> chr(126)
'~'
```

You can use negative indices to slice or select relative to the end of a string, no need to use `len(IV)` here:

```
IV = base64.b64decode(IV)
LastByte = IV[-1]
NewByte = chr(ord(LastByte) ^ x)
newIV = IV[:-1] + NewByte
newIV = base64.b64encode(newIV)
```

or, more concicely:

```
IV = base64.b64decode(IV)
newIV = base64.b64encode(IV[:-1] + chr(ord(IV[-1]) ^ x))
```

Demo:

```
>>> IV = 'NFhS0jOCAR0ymB2MM+3Pfg=='
>>> x = 128
>>> IV = base64.b64decode(IV)
>>> base64.b64encode(IV[:-1] + chr(ord(IV[-1]) ^ x))
'NFhS0jOCAR0ymB2MM+3P/g=='
```

Comment: chr() was the answer alright. My code now looks closer to what it should be doing but I'm still a ways away from my final goal. Big thanks!